# position: sticky in Chrome vs Safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, position, overflow

It seems like `position: sticky` is treated differently in Chrome and Safari. I will do my best to explain the issue, but please reference the fiddles and snippets below to *see* what is going on.

I have edited this post because I do not believe I did a good explaining what was going on in my first version.

**[Fiddle #1](https://jsfiddle.net/gLtb8u7r/)** - top value of 0

In this fiddle, the element with `sticky` positioning has a top value of `0`. That should essentially mean that the element is always `fixed`. In Safari, this shows the element kind of like "absolutely positioned to the parent element at the top 0 pixel".

It functions as I intend, but doesn't make much sense to me. **Why** does `top: 0` *relative to the parent* element when sticky positioned elements are supposed to be relative until they are fixed (and fixed elements are relative to the window *not the element*)?

What I am saying is that I expect to need to put a `top: 40px` value on the sticky element to get it to function the way I want, but it seems that I do *not*; great.

In that same fiddle, in Chrome, it functions how I am expecting. A `top: 0` value "fixes" the element at 0 pixels relative to the browser window *not* the parent element...

So, if I want to have the element function as I'd like (basically fixed within the parent), I set the `top` value to `40px`, except this doesn't work right.

**[Fiddle #2](https://jsfiddle.net/gLtb8u7r/1/)** - top value of 40px

This fiddle looks visually correct *in Chrome* but I am unable to interact with the input (unless I click "empty" space under it). In Safari, it functions correctly but looks *40px down from the parent element*.

It's obvious that these browsers are handling `position: sticky` differently.

**Which way is correct?** And is there any way to make it function correctly in each browser, respectively?

---

Please, I am not looking for suggestions how to accomplish the effect, but rather *why* there is such a difference between the browsers. An answerer below pointed out that they think this could be accomplished with a `position: fixed` element, but it **does not work out** that way (fixed element, within fixed element with overflow scrolling, in a body that has overflow hidden) when in this specific case: [See Example](https://jsfiddle.net/gLtb8u7r/2/)

---

**Fiddle #1 Snippet**

```js
document.getElementById("toggle").addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (document.body.classList.contains("show-tracking")) {
        document.body.classList.remove("show-tracking");
    } else {
        document.body.classList.add("show-tracking");
        fix_safari_scroll("tracking");
    }
});

function fix_safari_scroll(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.overflowY = "hidden";
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById(id).style.overflowY = "scroll";
        document.getElementById(id).removeAttribute("style");
    }, 200);
}
```

```css
header {
    background: blue;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}

#ticker,
#tracking {
    padding-top: 40px;
}

#ticker {
    background: grey;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#tracking {
    background: lightblue;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 5;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms ease-in;
    transition: -webkit-transform 200ms ease-in;
    transition: transform 200ms ease-in;
    transition: transform 200ms ease-in, -webkit-transform 200ms ease-in;
    max-height: 100vh;
}

.show-tracking {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.show-tracking #tracking {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.filter {
    background: yellow;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
    Header<button id="toggle">toggle</button>
</header>
<div id="ticker">
    <div style="padding: 400px 0;">ticker</div>
    ticcker
</div>
<div id="tracking">
    <div class="filter"><input type="text"></div>
    <div style="padding: 400px 0;">tracking</div>
    tracking
</div>
```

**Fiddle #2 Snippet**

```js
document.getElementById("toggle").addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (document.body.classList.contains("show-tracking")) {
        document.body.classList.remove("show-tracking");
    } else {
        document.body.classList.add("show-tracking");
        fix_safari_scroll("tracking");
    }
});

function fix_safari_scroll(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.overflowY = "hidden";
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById(id).style.overflowY = "scroll";
        document.getElementById(id).removeAttribute("style");
    }, 200);
}
```

```css
header {
    background: blue;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}

#ticker,
#tracking {
    padding-top: 40px;
}

#ticker {
    background: grey;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#tracking {
    background: lightblue;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 5;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms ease-in;
    transition: -webkit-transform 200ms ease-in;
    transition: transform 200ms ease-in;
    transition: transform 200ms ease-in, -webkit-transform 200ms ease-in;
    max-height: 100vh;
}

.show-tracking {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.show-tracking #tracking {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.filter {
    background: yellow;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    width: 100%;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
    Header<button id="toggle">toggle</button>
</header>
<div id="ticker">
    <div style="padding: 400px 0;">ticker</div>
    ticcker
</div>
<div id="tracking">
    <div class="filter"><input type="text"></div>
    <div style="padding: 400px 0;">tracking</div>
    tracking
</div>
```

**Example Fiddle Snippet**

```js
document.getElementById("toggle").addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (document.body.classList.contains("show-tracking")) {
        document.body.classList.remove("show-tracking");
    } else {
        document.body.classList.add("show-tracking");
        fix_safari_scroll("tracking");
    }
});

function fix_safari_scroll(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.overflowY = "hidden";
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById(id).style.overflowY = "scroll";
        document.getElementById(id).removeAttribute("style");
    }, 200);
}
```

```css
header {
    background: blue;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}

#ticker,
#tracking {
    padding-top: 40px;
}

#ticker {
    background: grey;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#tracking {
    background: lightblue;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 5;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms ease-in;
    transition: -webkit-transform 200ms ease-in;
    transition: transform 200ms ease-in;
    transition: transform 200ms ease-in, -webkit-transform 200ms ease-in;
    max-height: 100vh;
}

.show-tracking {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.show-tracking #tracking {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.filter {
    background: yellow;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
    Header<button id="toggle">toggle</button>
</header>
<div id="ticker">
    <div style="padding: 400px 0;">ticker</div>
    ticcker
</div>
<div id="tracking">
    <div class="filter"><input type="text"></div>
    <div style="padding: 400px 0;">tracking</div>
    tracking
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not following... the snippets behaves identically to me. First one show yellow header, then red sticky, and content moves through, both in Firefox as in Chrome. Second one show yellow header, then grey space that "moves", then red sticky, then content that also moves, and again, identical in both browsers. And I'm able to put texts on the inputs, on both snippets, on both browsers. Right now I'm on a Windows system, with latest standard version of both browsers

Comment: @FacundoCorradini I haven't checked on a Windows machine, I should probably have noted that in the question. On Mac, there is a difference in the behavior between Safari/Firefox and Chrome. In Fiddle #1 on Safari, everything works as expected, in Fiddle #2 on Safari the `sticky` element (red) is positioned 20px down from the top. In Fiddle #1 on Chrome the element isn't "stickied" but I can input text in the input, in Fiddle #2 on Chrome, the element is stickied but in order to input text I need to click "empty" space 20px down from where the element actually is

Comment: @FacundoCorradini I accidentally hit enter before I was done with my first comment, I added some explanation

Comment: I've noticed another difference between Chrome and Safari:

Chrome: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/36432/36235126-9adedc24-11a3-11e8-97df-a51f105bfc26.gif

Safari: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/36432/36235149-c9358866-11a3-11e8-9415-3dfdd62f57d3.gif

Note that in my case Safari is the expected behavior. Chrome seems to have trouble calculating the height of the sticky element.

Comment: @DanielBachhuber there is def. something wacky between the two browser. I still haven't figured out a good way to remedy the cross browser issues. Thanks for providing some imagery as well

Answer (score -2):

There is seemingly no need for the use of position:sticky in this case. The red input bar never needs to be scrolled in your example. Sticky helps provide a state change when an element is positioned at the top of the page. This element is fixed to a certain position from start to finish, so you can just use fixed position (or even absolute), here

```
    *,
*:before,
*:after  {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 18px;
  position: relative;
}

header {
  height: 20px;
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.el {
  background: grey;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  background: lightblue;
}

.content span {
  display: block;
  padding: 250px 0;
}

.sticky {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
}
```

Check out Apple's use of position:sticky here => https://www.apple.com/do-more/

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Regardless of whether there is a work around I asked *why the behavior is different between the browsers*, not *how do I accomplish this effect*.

Comment: @justinw I'm glad you've rewritten your question above. The answer you received from me may have been a reflection of the way it was originally worded. I understand your question a lot better now.

Comment: @justinw did you ever get your answer? It seems you ended up just asking why safari and chrome are different.